# Restful API for Templating

Tags: rest

I am struggling with a design aspect of my restful api for templating collections of resources.

The endpoint calls for a json with the name to a particular template and a collections of tokens. The API will then create entries into numerous tables and use the tokens where appropriate.

A very simple example is:

```
*{
    'template': 'DeviceTemplate'
    'tokens': [
         'customer': 1234,
         'serial_number': '12312RF3242a', 
         'ip_address': '1.1.1.1'
    ]
}*
```

This creates a new device for the customer with that ip address along with several other objects, for instance interfaces, device users etc etc. I use the tokens in various places where needed.

I'm not sure how to make this endpoint restful.

The endpoint for `/device` is already taken if you want to create this resource individually. The endpoint I need is for creating everything via the template.

I want to reserve the POST `/template` endpoint for creating the actual template itself and not for implementing it with the tokens to create the various objects.

**I want to know how to call the endpoint without using a verbs.**

**I also want to know if its a good idea to structure a POST with a nested JSON.**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you create an action on the template object itself. So right now if you do `/templates/<id>` you are given an object. You should include in that object a url endpoint for instantiating an instance of that template. Github follows a scheme that I like a lot [1] where within an object there will be a key pointing to another url with a suffix `_url`. So for instance, your response could be something like:

```
{
    "template": "DeviceTemplate",
    "id": "127",
    ...
    "create_url": "https://yourdomain.com/templates/127/create",
    ...
}
```

Then this way you treat a POST to that endpoint the same as if this template (DeviceTemplate) was its own resource.

The way to conceptualize this is you're calling a method on an object instead of calling a function.

[1] - For example https://developer.github.com/v3/#failed-login-limit

Comment: I agree in having the action with the json payload of the GET, however, I was trying to avoid using verbs in my endpoints where you suggested to use https://yourdomain.com/templates/127/create

You did give me an idea, perhaps I can construct the endpoint as such:

POST /templates/device
{
    [
        "customer": 1234,
        "serial": "12312RF3242a",
        'ip_address': '1.1.1.1'
    ]
}

where the name after templates in the URL 'device' is the template name, and the body is is a list of tokens to apply to the template.